# jQuery syntax problems with .action()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok guys I'm trying to learn jQuery but I can't understood a thing which I searched for about 2 hours, look what this page say: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

```
Basic syntax is: $(selector).action()

    A $ sign to define/access jQuery
    A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements
    A jQuery action() to be performed on the element(s)
```

`.action()` is beside `$(selector)`, but if you look for example at this code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
```

Beside of the selector you can find an event, not an action, why?Another question, if you look at the code on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp or at mine that I wrote up there is inside the event a `function()` but this function is not declared, why?
Thanks for read have a  great day

Comment: `$("button").click(` is the `$(selector).action()`  - the "event" is the "click" - it's the same thing just you're calling it an "event".   Someone else might call it an "event handler".  Or, if you're reading w3schools it might explain events on the next page or a couple of pages later.  The `$('p').hide()` is the `callback` or `event handler`.  It's an `anonymous function` so does not need a separate function declaration.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. The jQuery docs are far more comprehensive and accurate: http://learn.jquery.com and http://api.jquery.com

Comment: First, w3schools is not the best source of information. That said, they're describing the general pattern of jQuery usage: create a jQuery object, and then make jQuery method calls.

Comment: Think of the `click` as the “`action`”. That action takes an argument. In this case, the argument is simply a function. When passing function expressions, they don’t need to have a name, only function declarations need to have one.

Comment: But most of the beginners start their journey from W3Schools only :(

Comment: Thanks all of the support now I understood!